# How to install SQL Server Native Client 11.0 on UBUNTU?

Tags: sql-server, ubuntu-16.04

Is there any tutorial on how to install SQL Server Native Client on Ubuntu. Cause in the below Image I want to configure DSN.

```
/etc/odbc.ini

[login]
// Driver = SQL Server Native Client // the driver is not working
// but when I used the 
Driver = ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server // is now working
Server = myhost.com 
Database = MYDATABASE_DBF
```

[image]

Comment: I've just googled "install sql server on ubuntu" and there's a lot of documentation available, may be worth a try. Asking for an offsite resource is off topic for stack overflow so this question may well get closed. If you have a specific question about a part of the installation then it may be worth posting that as it's own question.

Comment: I've already installed SQL SERVER

Comment: I'm asking for help on "How do I install the SQL serer native client driver"

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh568451(v=sql.110).aspx

Comment: @RichBenner the question is very specific and *not* asking about an offsite resource.

Comment: SQL Server for Linux is still SQL Server. What language are you using? In .NET the natural choice is to use ADO.NET. ODBC is used mainly in C++ programs

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos "Is there any tutorial" stack overflow doesn't contain tutorials, it contains questions and answers.

Comment: @RichBenner and that's exactly what this was. Check the answer, and you'll see that this is *not* an installation question, nor a question about any tutorial. A *lot* of SO questions are actually XY questions - asking about one thing while looking for another. It's easy to spot them if you have experience on a subject. In this case, how to call SQL Server on Linux

Comment: @RichBenner you'll also find that many, many questions with the world "tutorial" receive answers from people with 6 figure rep instead of closing. The rules aren't set in stone, they are there to *help*.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos my apologies, I seem to have rustled some feathers here. From my read of the question and seeing the words "tutorial" and "install" in the first sentence I must have misunderstood this as a question asking for a tutorial on how to install SQL Server Native Client on Ubuntu.

Comment: @RichBenner let's just say that I regret half my close votes.

Answer (score 3):

There are several ways to connect to SQL Server.  The native client is one.  But it is not recommended by Microsoft for new development work.  In your case you probably want the *Microsoft ODBC Driver for SQL Server*.  See [the link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh568451(v=sql.110).aspx) helpfully provide by @HongOoi for more on this.

[This link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms810810.aspx) contains an overview, from  Microsoft, on the various connection options they support.  It includes this comment on the native client:

> The SQL Server Native Client OLE DB provider was included in SQL Server Native Client in SQL Server 2005, SQL Server 2008, SQL Server 2008 R2, and SQL Server 2012. After SQL Server 2012, the SQL Server Native Client OLE DB provider will no longer be included in SQL Server Native Client.
>
> After SQL Server 2012, the ODBC driver will be updated for the most
>   recent server features, including Microsoft Windows Azure SQL
>   Database, and released as the Microsoft ODBC Driver for SQL Server.

Comment: I installed the mssql server on Ubuntu 16.04 server, is it ok to use the ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server instead of using the SQL Server Native Client??

Comment: I've never tried it.  But that was the impression I got when reading the documentation.

Comment: @ronscript the client you use depends on your *OS* and *language*. You posted a Windows screenshot for ODBC sources. In Windows, you can use ADO.NET for .NET programming, OLEDB for COM programming and ODBC for C++.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I am using Ubuntu, i need to replicate the configuration on Ubunntu

Comment: And which language are you programming in?

Answer (score 0):

On Mint (Tara) I installed msodbcsql17. It connects to a SQLServer 2008R2 on Windows server.

```
curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/18.04/prod.list > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-release.list
sudo apt-get update
sudo ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get install msodbcsql17
```

My Config to the TEST database: /etc/odbc.ini

```
[MSDB]
Driver=ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server
Description = SQLServer Driver
Trace = No
Server = 192.168.123.112
Port=1433
Database = TEST
Protocol = 8.0
```

NOTE: /etc/odbcinst.ini is created automatically.

Test the connection: isql MSDB USER PWD